# Is QNE pressure altitude?

Tags: altitude

In trying to understand pressure altitude better, am I wrong or right when I say this?

I am at an airfield. The pressure altitude at that airfield is 200 ft a.m.s.l.

If I set subscale 1013 mb on my altimeter, the altimeter should, theoretically, indicate 200 ft a.m.s.l.

Am I wrong or right when I say this? And am I right in thinking along these lines in trying to understand pressure altitude better?

Comment: If there is something you don't understand in the definition of QNH (e.g. as defined by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altimeter_setting) or [skybrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Altimeter_Pressure_Settings)), don't hesitate to precise it so that answers can be adapted to your current level of comprehension.

Comment: You can not edit the original question to make it ask an entirely different question all together. That is not the purpose of this site. It is not meant to be conversational. Please roll back your edit to its original form. If you wish to ask a brand new question, please use the “Ask Question” button to ask a new question.

Comment: Lungelo, I had to rollback your question to the previous version because you completely changed it. This invalidates the existing answer! You have to [ask a new question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for that.

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct. There are three different altitude systems:

**True altitude** is the height above Mean Sea Level (**MSL**). This is what you get when you set your altimeter to **QNH**. Using this, your altimeter should read 200ft when you are on the runway if the airport elevation is listed as 200ft MSL.

**Absolute altitude** is the height Above Ground Level (**AGL**). This is what you get when you set your altimeter to **QFE**.  Using this, your altimeter should read 0ft when you are on the runway.

**Pressure altitude** has no relation to the ground *or* sea level. This is what you get when you set your altimeter to **QNE** (always 1013 or 29.92). You *never* use this near the surface of the Earth, only when up high enough that terrain or obstacles clearance isn't a concern. Pressure altitudes are expressed as Flight Levels (**FL**), with the last two digits omitted.